# Transferring from Dreamweaver to MySQL with MAMP

Tags: mysql, forms, dreamweaver, mamp, transfer

I have been developing a Form on my website (that I have been building with Dreamweaver) that will automatically post to a MySQL database, but I have found surprisingly little information on the subject. I am hoping to find some assistance here at Stack Overflow. I am on a Macintosh system so I will need to use MAMP. I know very little about where to start and what to do. Basically any information on the process would help me, and code would be nice too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using PHP? Perl? Python? I think it would be helpful if you could give more details about what you've already done since you say you have already been developing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dreamweaver, all you need to do is configure the database connection from the Database panel, then add the Insert Record behavior.  The wizard will walk you through the basic steps from there.